# Why is my group list only rendering 1 sprite at a time?

Tags: python, list, pygame, sprite, render

I recently watched Tech with Mike's space invaders video, and I thought the group lists were interesting. I tried to make a particle list with it. It works until the particles fall to the bottom, and I'm having trouble recycling them. It doesn't render everything, only one cube.

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
win_height=600
win_width=800
win=pygame.display.set_mode((win_width,win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("List practice")
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

class particle_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface((25,25))
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed=0
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y+=self.speed
        
particles=pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(100):
    particle=particle_class()
    particle.speed=random.randrange(5,11)
    particle.rect.y=0
    particle.rect.x=random.randrange(0,win_width+1)
    particles.add(particle)

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    win.fill(black)
    particles.update()
    particles.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
    for i in particles:
        if particle.rect.y>win_height:
            particle.rect.y=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate through the list of `particles`. The `for` loop runs on each item in the list (iterable) and gives you access to the current item in the list. If you do `for i in particles:`, `i` is an element of the list. `i` is just the name of the variable that refers to the current item in the list. You can use any name you want at this place (`i`, `particle`, `hugo`, ...). You just need to use the same name (variable) in the loop to access the item. See [`for` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Either

```py
for i in particles:
   if i.rect.y > win_height:
       i.rect.y = 0
```

or

```py
for particle in particles:
    if particle.rect.y > win_height:
        particle.rect.y = 0
```

Comment: So does the word after for have to be the same variable used to contain the class?

Comment: @ree The identifier after `for` is just the name of the variable. It can be any name. e.g. `for hugo in particles:` `if hugo.rect.y > .....`. With this variable you can access the current element of the list.

Comment: This helps, I know it says to avoid thanks comments but thanks anyways.

Comment: @ree Thank you. You're welcome. (I don't think it's a mistake to be polite)